# Check regexp condition inside while loop (shell)

Tags: regex, shell, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have problem with running my simple shell script, where I am using while loop to read text file and trying to check condition with matching regexp:

```
#!/bin/sh
regex="^sometext"


cat input.txt | 
{
  while read string
    do if [[ $string ~= $regex ]]; then
            echo "$string" | awk '{print $1}' >> output.txt
       else
            echo "$string" >> outfile.txt
       fi
    done
}
```

but I recieve only errors like

```
[[: not found
```

could you please advise me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using shebang for `/bin/sh` and `[[` is only available in BASH.

Change shebang to `/bin/bash`

btw your script can be totally handled in simple awk and you don't need to use `awk` inside the `while` loop here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this. So if I have no bash I can't use this condition?

Comment: Yes that's correct if you don't have BASH then you can't use `=~` regex operator either.

Answer (score 3):

`[[ expr ]]` is a bash-ism; sh doesn't have it.

Use `#!/bin/bash` if you want to use that syntax.

---

#### That said, why use a shell script?

Awk can already do everything you're doing here - you just need to take advantage of Awk's built-in regex matching and the ability to have multiple actions per line:

Your original script can be reduced to this command:

```
awk '/^sometext/ {print $1; next} {print}' input.txt >> output.txt
```

If the pattern matches, Awk will run the first `{}`-block, which does a `print $1` and then forces Awk to move to the next line. Otherwise, it'll continue on to the second `{}`-block, which just prints the line.

Comment: @anubhava I don't generally try to race.

Comment: Thanks for comment! I simplified my script a bit to post here. Full command after checking condition is `echo "$string" | awk '{print $1}' | base64 -d | iconv -f UTF-8 -t KOI8-R >> outfile.txt`

Comment: @Amber: Don't take it otherwise, all 3 of us answered pretty much same thing that's why I commented.

Comment: @Amber: I think I'll do it :)

Comment: @P.S. One way to simplify would make to make a shell script that just does the chain of commands you want to do on a particular line, and then use awk to invoke the shell script for only the relevant lines - `{print $1 | "myscript.sh"; close("myscript.sh"); next}` (the close ensures that the output from the script comes before any next printed line).

Answer (score 1):

`sh` does not support the double bracket syntax - that's explicitly a `bash`-ism.

Try changing your shebang line to `#!/bin/bash`